Flux HelmRelease valuesFrom behaviour
How is the Flux valuesFrom applied on the chart? It seems that valuesFrom will not override existing values in the Helm chart values.yaml. See example below. When I check the release then it shows the values of values.yaml in the env tag.
Example:
values.yaml
env:
  database:
    user: test-user
    password: test-password

Secret
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: test-secret
  namespace: test-namespace
.data:
  secret-value:
    user: actual-user
    password: actual-password

HelmRelease
### REST of HelmRelease
valuesFrom:
  - kind: Secret
    name: test-secret
    valuesKey: secret-value
    targetPath: env.database

Result
env:
  database:
    user: test-user
    password: test-password


Not sure if this answers your question, but from the flux documentation: ".spec.valuesFrom is an optional list to refer to ConfigMap and Secret resources from which to take values. The values are merged in the order given, with the later values overwriting earlier, and then inline values overwriting those."

Is there a reason you aren't using envFrom directly with the secret?
